# Singly Linked list implementation in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

How can I improve this code
Please tell proper indentation and usage of camel-case.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* Create(int data){
    Node* root=new Node();
    root->data=data;
    root->next=NULL;
    Node* head=root;
    return head;    
}
void push_back(int data,Node* head){
    if(!head->next)
    {
        Node* newNode=new Node();
        newNode->data=data;
        newNode->next=NULL;
        head->next=newNode;
    }   
    else 
        push_back(data,head->next);
}
Node* push_front(int data,Node* head){
    Node* newNode=new Node();
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=head;
    head=newNode;
    return head;
}
void pull_back(Node* head){
    Node* temp=head;
    if(!temp->next)
        delete temp;
    else
        pull_back(temp->next);
}
Node* pull_front(Node* head){
    Node* temp=head->next;
    delete head;
    Node* NewHead=temp;
    return NewHead;
}
void print(Node* head){
    while(head)
        cout<<head->data<<" ",
        head=head->next;
    cout<<"\n";
}
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    Node* prev   = NULL;
    Node* current = head;
    Node* next;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next  = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;   
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = prev;
    return head;
}
int Search(int data,Node* head,int count=1){
    if(head->data==data)
        return count;
    if(!head->next)
        return -1;
    return Search(data,head->next,count+1);
}
Node* MakeCircular(Node* head)
{
    Node* temp=head;
    while(!temp->next)
        temp=temp->next;
    temp->next=head;
    return head;
}
bool DetectCircle(Node* head){
    //using floyd's cycle
    Node* fast=head;
    Node* slow=head;
    if(!(slow && slow->next))return false;
    while(fast && fast->next){
        slow=slow->next;
        fast=fast->next->next;
        if(slow==fast)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Node* head=Create(12);
    push_back(32,head);
    push_back(123,head);
    head=push_front(-21,head);
    print(head);
    head=Reverse(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To whoever flagged this for off-topic as "unclear what you are asking", read the title; it says the code's purpose right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the small stuff, to get in the groove.

**Naming convention**

Whether you use camelCase or PascalCase or snake_case does not matter, as long as you do so *consistently*.

Pick a style for your class names, the same or another style for your functions, etc... and stick to it.

I will assume that you go for PascalCase for classes and snake_case for methods, but do as YOU wish.

**Spaces**

The C++ grammar allows you not to put spaces around operators, however this really hurts readability.

Use spaces:

- after commas: `push_back(int data, Node* head)`
- after keywords: `if (...)`, `while (...)`, ...
- around operators: `a = b`, `a + b`, `! a`, ...

The goal is to make sure that your eye does not accidentally "merge" two symbols and treat them as one. For example, `!a` and `la` are very close graphically speaking, yet they mean completely different things.

**Useless code**

Avoid writing code that does not bring anything to the table:

```
Node* Create(int data){
    Node* root=new Node();
    root->data=data;
    root->next=NULL;
    Node* head=root;
    return head;    
}
```

There is no reason to create a `head` variable here. You can simply return `root` directly.

**Inconsistencies**

Why does `pull_front` return `Node*` but `pull_back` return `void`?

This is even more problematic in that the user need to remember than she needs to call `delete` on the result of `pull_front` but there is no result to `pull_back`...

*Side Note: one would expect `pop_front` and `pop_back`, as far as names go.*

---

Let's now move on to more interesting stuff.

**Dynamic Memory Allocation**

For production code, using `new` or `delete` is forbidden<sup>1</sup>. You should be using `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or one of the many Standard Library containers.

Since you do not appear to be familiar with `unique_ptr`, I advise you to add them to your reading list and will use naked pointers for the rest of this answer.

<sup>1</sup> *Unless you are an experienced developer, and no other language facility or library allows you to write this code, and your colleagues have extensively reviewed your code.*

**Initialize your values**

Whenever you build a `Node`, you have to explicitly remember to initialize the `next` member to `nullptr` and the `data` member to `0`, lest they have garbage values.

Instead, use automatic initialization and constructors:

```
struct Node {
    Node() {}
    Node(int d, Node* n): data(d), next(n) {}

    int data = 0;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};
```

**Beware of recursion**

While recursion is elegant, in languages like C++ it can lead to Stack Overflow.

As such, unbounded recursion should be avoided, and therefore your implementation of `push_back` or `pull_back` or `Search` should be converted to an iterative approach (use a `while` loop).

**Encapsulation**

It is generally recommended to encapsulate functionality. At the moment, anybody can fiddle with your `Node` internals (and point its `next` member to whatever they want without using your functions).

Once `next` becomes `private` however, only a specific set of functions will be able to access it:

- member functions (object-oriented approach)
- friend non-member functions

This ties in with the bigger question of whether you really want to expose the `Node` itself, where a null node represents an empty list and the user has to explicitly call `delete` on nodes you return. I would recommend to avoid exposing pointers and therefore to create a `List` class with an inner `Node` struct.

---

Let's see the code!

*Note: I will not transpose all the code, only the first few methods.*

```
class List {
public:
    List() {}

    bool is_empty() const { return this->head == nullptr; }

    void push_front(int value) {
        this->head = new Node(value, this->head);
    }

    void push_back(int value) {
        if (this->head == nullptr) {
            this->head = new Node(value, nullptr);
            return;
        }

        Node* current = this->head;
        while (current->next != nullptr) { current = current->next; }

        current->next = new Node(value, nullptr);
    }

    int pop_front() {
        assert(!this->empty(), "Cannot pop on empty list.");

        Node* popped = this->head;
        this->head = popped->next;

        int const value = popped->data;
        delete popped;

        return value;
    }

    int pop_back() {
        assert(!this->empty(), "Cannot pop on empty list.");

        Node* current = this->head;
        while (current->next != nullptr) { current = current->next; }

        int const value = current->next->data;
        delete current->next;
        current->next = nullptr;

        return value;
    }

    // ...

private:
    struct Node {
        Node() {}
        Node(int d, Node* n): data(d), next(n) {}

        int data = 0;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };

    Node* head = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: `go for PascalCase for classes and snake_case` Python style in C++? That's interesting... Is it common nowadays in C++?

Comment: @JuhaUntinen: I have no idea what's common and what's not, to be honest. The standard uses snake_case exclusively, my company uses PascalCase for classes and functions and camelCase for methods, I have seen PascalCase only styles, ... I am mostly toying with Rust at the moment, so I went with the Rust convention :)

Answer (score 16):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Prefer references to raw pointers

In modern C++, we tend not to use raw pointers very often.  In this case, It would probably be better to have two different classes, one would be a `LinkedList` class and the other would be a `Node` class.  That way, instead of starting with a pointer, you can start with an object.

### Use objects

You have a `Node` structure and then separate functions that operate on `Node` data. With only a slight syntax change, you would have a real object instead of C-style code written in C++.

### Use whitespace to improve readability

Lines like this:

```
head=push_front(-21,head);
```

become much easier to read with a little bit of whitespace:

```
head = push_front(-21, head);
```

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Use consistent naming

The code includes `print()` (lowercase) and `Search()` (uppercase).  It would be better for both functions to have similar case.  I tend to use capital letters to name clases or structs such a `Node` and then lowercase letters for functions such as `print` or `search`.

### Match `new` with `delete`

If you allocate memory using `new`, you must also free it using `delete` or your program will leak memory.  This program leaks memory.

### Use more descriptive names

The code's `DetectCircle` function seems to return `true` if the list is circular.  Generally, it's good to name boolean functions so that their sense is unambiguous.  For example, I'd probably call it `isCircular`.

### Omit `return 0`

If your program completes successfully, the `return 0` at the end of `main()` will be generated automatically, so it's not needed in C++ programs.

Comment: Good points.  I disagree with the last one though (removing `return 0;`) -- it's good to be aware of the implicit behavior dictated by the standard, but it's far from problematic to make it explicit and consistent.

Comment: Considering the last point: Moreover, even if unlikely, you could compile on a target where 0 is not equal to `EXIT_SUCCESS` .. thus the implicit return 0 could mean a different thing.

Comment: On omitting `return 0`: I don't claim it's "problematic", merely that it's not needed.  Second, the standard explicitly states that an implicit return is the equivalent of `return 0` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS`, so if anything, it's a point in favor of my suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

This is a really straightforward implementation, and it's easy to follow. The code is very readable and I like that in your comments you mention which algorithm you're using to detect cycles. That way someone can look it up if they're not familiar with it. Below are some suggestions for improvements.

## Object Oriented Programming

The first thing that strikes me about this code is that it's in C++ but it's not very object oriented. Usually a list is a class. That way all the data and methods for manipulating the data are contained in 1 place. If it were my code, I'd make a class like this:

```
class List {
    public:
        List();
        virtual ~List();

        void push_back(const int data);
        void push_front(const int data);
        int pull_back();
        int pull_front();
        // ... other methods
    private:
        Node* head;
};
```

Then to use it, you would construct a `List` object and call methods on it. The calling code wouldn't need to see the implementation at all, so you could change the underlying implementation and as long as the interface was the same, users would be none the wiser.

## Don't Repeat Yourself

A good rule of thumb for any code that allocates memory is to only ever allocate that type of memory in a single place. In this case I see you've written essentially the same code as the `Create()` function in 2 additional places - `push_back()` and `push_front()`. Those 2 functions should just call `Create()`:

```
void push_back(int data, Node* head) {
    if(!head->next)
    {
        Node* newNode=Create(data);
        head->next=newNode;
    }   
    else 
        push_back(data,head->next);
}
```

Also, in your `Create()` method, the last 2 lines are unnecessary. It should just be:

```
Node* Create(int data){
    Node* root=new Node();
    root->data=data;
    root->next=NULL;
    return root;
}
```

## Don't Try to be Clever

Your `print()` method is confusing. The `while` statement doesn't have brackets around it, which makes it look like the following line has an error. It doesn't, but that use of a comma is tricky. It should instead look like this:

```
void print(Node* head){
    while(head)
    {
        cout<<head->data<<" ";
        head=head->next;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

That's much easier to read and understand.

## Const

In most of your functions you're changing the `Node`, but not the data you pass in. If data doesn't change in a method, you should mark it `const` so the compiler knows it won't be changed and can display an error if you try to change it in the future. It may also be able to apply some optimizations to the code, too.

Comment: Please, remove that `virtual`! `List` is not a polymorphic class, so it certainly does NOT need a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Good points, in addition to that I have observed that whereas

`using namespace std::cout;`

is declared globally, `cout` is only used in two functions. It would be preferable to just use

`std::cout << /* say something*/ << std::endl;`

or `std::cout << /* say something */ << "\n";`